# Query multiple tables that have date pattern appended to their names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a database that creates a new table for each new day. The naming of the tables follows this pattern: History_tbl_[year]_[month]_[day]. A sample name of the tables for the last 5 days for example is:

```
History_tbl_2021_10_02
History_tbl_2021_10_01
History_tbl_2021_09_30
History_tbl_2021_09_29
History_tbl_2021_09_28
```

My goal is to be able to query all the tables from a given date range at once. I can manually select the tables with union all, but it takes lots of time especially if I want to do a long date range. Is there a better way to solve this?

Note: Unfortunately, I don't have the privilege to change the structure and make all data being stored in a single table.

Comment: The way you solve it is to properly normalise the data and store it in one table with a date column - you then do not have a problem!

Comment: @stu thank you for the suggestion, but I, unfortunately, don't have the privilege to do so.  For now, I have to deal with it as it is.

Comment: Then you are going ideally have a calendar table and dynamic SQL to generate multiple statements to union results.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you, I'll try to solve it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bare-bones method to generate a list of unioned queries and dynamically execute them would be as follows, tweak as necessary:

```
declare @from date='20211001', @to date='20211004', @sql nvarchar(max)='';

with d as (
    select DateAdd(day, number, @from) dt
    from master..spt_values
    where type = 'P'
    and DateAdd(day, number, @from) <= @to
)
select @sql=String_Agg(qry,' ')
from (
    select 'select col1, col2, col3 from History_tbl_' 
        + Concat(Year(dt),'_',Right(Concat('0',month(dt)),2),'_',  Right(Concat('0',Day(dt)),2)) 
        + Iif( dt=Max(dt) over()  ,'', ' union all')  qry
    from d
) x

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that the CTE generates the date range on the fly, ideally you would use a permanent [calendar table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table)

Comment: That works, thanks! only hickup is the table name for day is '1' instead of '01'. Same for the month, which prevents the query from running. Is there a way to make it digits instead of one?

Comment: Lots of ways, I have edited above with an example

Comment: You really shouldn't use variable coalescing `select @x += something` because it has undefined behaviour, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697. Instead use `FOR XML` or `STRING_AGG`

Comment: I've never experienced any ordering issues with this particular string aggregation method, however it's very easy to use string_agg and I have edited for the OP using that option.

Comment: @stu can you please tell me how to see the resulting query of the commands above before executing them? I have some errors and I want to check the query generated to make some tweaks to it.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

The WITH clause establishes a common table expression (CTE) named RecentTables. This CTE selects the table_name column from the information_schema.tables view. It filters for tables in the 'dbo' schema (table_schema = 'dbo') that start with 'exampledata_' (table_name LIKE 'exampledata_%'). The results are sorted in descending order by table_name (latest tables first) and are limited to 12 rows using LIMIT 12.

The main query then selects all columns from the RecentTables CTE.

This query is particularly useful when you need to quickly identify and analyze the latest tables created in the 'dbo' schema, especially when dealing with datasets where tables are frequently added or updated.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thanks for your guidance next time I will make sure that there is a proper explanation of code must be there.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer this time? Answers around here tend to be referenced for years to come, so it’s helpful to ensure they continue to be useful to the community, and not simply the original person asking the question.